# What is this technique for matching cabinet veneers called?

Tags: wood, custom-cabinetry

Check out this picture of a kitchen cabinet:

[image: picture of kitchen cabinet]

Notice how the veneers of the cabinets match up perfectly! What's this technique called? My architect said we should just specify "book-matched veneers" but that doesn't quite capture what I'm seeing here where the individual cabinet and drawer faces appear to be cut out of a single piece of wood.

Comment: It looks like that section _is_ book matched 2.5 times over then the entire piece is cut again to veneer the doors and cabinet

Answer (score 5):

Those veneers are without doubt book-matched, but I would say in a very specific method, "Architectural end matching" (End or Butt Matching):

- [Matching between leaves](http://www.veneernet.com/matching.html)

P.S. That is some top quality veneering, the attention to detail is almost pure art (the cabinet maker that did that work is an artisan).

This morning on twitter, I asked a few woodworking experts (at least I consider them experts) to take a look at your question:

- [My initial tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/MikePerry/status/91157545317707776)
- [@WoodWhisperer initial reply](https://twitter.com/#!/WoodWhisperer/status/91167544869793792)
- [@MBWPodcast reply](https://twitter.com/#!/MBWPodcast/status/91168592074244096)
- [@WoodWhisperer follow on reply](https://twitter.com/#!/WoodWhisperer/status/91169329785208832)
- [@RenaissanceWW reply](https://twitter.com/#!/RenaissanceWW/status/91180384888434689)

Answer (score 4):

With most veneer work only the panels (here, the doors) would be veneered and frames would be solid wood (or at least they would have some solid wood applied to the edges for durability). So, if you have a written specification for your project and you request bookmatched, or end matched, you are not likely to get the effect you want.

If you want to specify this for a project, I would include the image you showed us, or a diagram and written instructions accompanying, e.g. "bookmatched veneers with continuous matching over panel and adjacent cabinet frame edges".

Answer (score 0):

Bank and bookmatched vertical grain.